# Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Can you check next statements, and they are proofs?

**Statement 1.** Lets $A, A_1, A_2$ - are abelian groups and
$$A = A_1\oplus A_2.$$
Then
$$A/A_1=A_2.$$
**Proof:**
$$A=\{(a_1, a_2)|a_1\in A_1,~~a_2\in A_2\}.$$
$$x = (x_1, x_2)\sim y = (y_1, y_2)\Leftrightarrow x-y\in A_1 \Leftrightarrow x_2=y_2.$$
So, homomorphism $\varphi : A/A_1\to A_2$, such that
$$\varphi(a_1, a_2) = a_2,$$
is isomorphism.
$\blacksquare$

**Statement 2.** Lets $A\supset B$ - abelian, then
$$A = B\oplus A/B$$

**Proof:**
$A\supset B$, therefore
$$\exists C\subset A: A=B\oplus C.$$
And from first statement:
$$C = A/B.$$
$\blacksquare$

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bad sign in a proof when you have a statement with no attempt to justify it. *Why* does $A \supset B$ imply the existence of a $C$ such that $A=B \oplus C$?

Comment: It should be true, at least for finitely generated abelian groups, that any quotient will appear as a subgroup. But Prof Magidin's example shows that you can't expect this to give a direct sum decomposition.

Comment: (2⊕4)/(1⊕2) ≅ 2⊕2 ≠ 4, so you have to make sure to use the right copy of A1 in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First statement: you don't have equality between $A/A_1$ and $A_2$, you have *isomorphism*.

The second statement: you cannot hope for equality in general, though you may hope for isomorphism. However, Statement 2 is false: take $A$ to be cyclic of order $4$, $B$ to be the unique cyclic subgroup of order $2$. Then $A/B$ is cyclic of order $2$, so your assertion is that the cyclic group of order $4$ (namely, $A$) is isomorphic to a direct sum of a cyclic group of order $2$ (namely $B$) and another cyclic group of order $2$ (namely, $A/B$). This is false.

The error lies in the assertion that there must exist a $C$ contained in $A$ such that $A=B\oplus C$. There is no warrant for this assertion, as you can see with the example above.